# Looping all Variables in Data.table to create n-lags

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table, lag

I  have a data.table with 200 obs and 20 variables, and I need to get n-lags from those 20 variables in a loop.

I was trying something like the following, but is not working properly.

Please any help?

> nombresvar = names(Model_X)
>
> for (j in nombresvar) for(i in 1:3)
>
> Model_X[,c(paste0(j, i)) := lag(c(paste0('Model_X$', j)), i)]

The problem is coming from the **Lag Function**, as my code seems not to work properly, when trying to produce 4 lags variables per VariablesNames are in Nombresvar vector.

The lag function for each loop should have been something like the following:

```
lag ( ModelX$Variable1, 1)
lag ( ModelX$Variable1, 2)
lag ( ModelX$Variable1, 3)
lag ( ModelX$Variable2, 1)
....
lag ( ModelX$VariableN, 3)
```

Comment: Data.table has a `shift` function for this; maybe see `?shift`.

Comment: @duckmayr The OP has `**` in that code, presumably to bold part of it. If you write it in a code block, however, it's broken code.

Comment: See answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186677/how-to-loop-lapply-to-create-lag-terms-over-multiple-variables-in-r?rq=1

Comment: @Frank Got it -- good catch.

Comment: imho provide some dummy data in the same structure as your problem... so that we can work with something as the code above seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to create the additional lag columns. The `n` parameter to `data-table`'s `shift()` function is defined as

> Non-negative integer vector denoting the offset to lead or lag the
>   input by. To create multiple lead/lag vectors, provide multiple values
>   to n

So,

```
DT[, shift(baz, 0:3)]
```

returns

> ```
>     V1 V2 V3 V4
>  1:  3 NA NA NA
>  2:  6  3 NA NA
>  3:  9  6  3 NA
>  4: 12  9  6  3
>  5: 15 12  9  6
>  6: 18 15 12  9
>  7: 21 18 15 12
>  8: 24 21 18 15
>  9: 27 24 21 18
> 10: 30 27 24 21
> ```

Now, the OP has requested to shift each variable and to name the new columns according to the amount of shift. This can be accomplished by

```
DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, shift, n = 0:3), recursive = FALSE)]
```

> ```
>     foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4 baz1 baz2 baz3 baz4
>  1:    1   NA   NA   NA    2   NA   NA   NA    3   NA   NA   NA
>  2:    2    1   NA   NA    4    2   NA   NA    6    3   NA   NA
>  3:    3    2    1   NA    6    4    2   NA    9    6    3   NA
>  4:    4    3    2    1    8    6    4    2   12    9    6    3
>  5:    5    4    3    2   10    8    6    4   15   12    9    6
>  6:    6    5    4    3   12   10    8    6   18   15   12    9
>  7:    7    6    5    4   14   12   10    8   21   18   15   12
>  8:    8    7    6    5   16   14   12   10   24   21   18   15
>  9:    9    8    7    6   18   16   14   12   27   24   21   18
> 10:   10    9    8    7   20   18   16   14   30   27   24   21
> ```

#### Data

For comparison, the sample data of [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49369826/3817004) is used

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(foo = seq_len(10),
                 bar = seq_len(10)*2L,
                 baz = seq_len(10)*3L)
```

Comment: Hi How about shifting 1 column only and name that column? thanks

Comment: @Gabriel, probably something like  `DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, shift, n = 0:3), recursive = FALSE), .SDcols = "foo"]` will create lags only for column `foo` (untested).

Comment: I figured it out by using DT[, sprintf("foo%d", 1:4) := shift(foo, 1:4, type = "lag")]

Comment: @Gabriel, glad you found a solution for your add-on question.

Comment: On a side note, does anyone know how to use a string to do operations inside J?

i.e. I want to sum all foo1+foo2+foo3+foo4 in J but without typing the actual column name?

Comment: @Gabriel, please, search SO or post a separate question including a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your asking:

```
# Random data 200 obs, 20 vars 
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(20,sample(0:100,200,rep=TRUE)))

# fucntion for getting lags
lags <- function(x,lag) { 
  lag(x,lag) 
}

require(dplyr) # using lag from dplyr (has opposite lead)
# lapply saves lags to a list 
lag1 <- lapply(df,lags, lag =1)
lag2 <- lapply(df,lags, lag =2)
lag3 <- lapply(df,lags, lag =3)

# cbind to data frame 
lag_1_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lag1))
lag_2_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lag2))
lag_3_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lag3))

# names 
names_lag1 <- rep(1,length(lag_1_df))
var_names <- rep(1:length(lag_1_df),1)
var_names <- paste("var",var_names)
names_lag1 <- paste(var_names,"lag",names_lag1)
colnames(lag_1_df) <- names_lag1
# column names lag 2
names_lag2 <- rep(2,length(lag_2_df))
var_names <- rep(1:length(lag_2_df),1)
var_names <- paste("var",var_names)
names_lag2 <- paste(var_names,"lag",names_lag2)
colnames(lag_2_df) <- names_lag2
# column names lag 3
names_lag3 <- rep(3,length(lag_3_df))
var_names <- rep(1:length(lag_3_df),1)
var_names <- paste("var",var_names)
names_lag3 <- paste(var_names,"lag",names_lag3)
colnames(lag_3_df) <- names_lag3


# Place all in same data frame 
all_df <- cbind(lag_1_df,lag_2_df,lag_3_df)
head(all_df)
```

With output:

```
> head(all_df)
  var 1 lag 1 var 2 lag 1 var 3 lag 1 var 4 lag 1 var 5 lag 1 var 6 lag 1 var 7 lag 1 var 8 lag 1 var 9 lag 1
1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
2          26          27          66          82          86          53          37          24          13
3          37          22          18          93           3          69          74          65           4
4          57          52          96          14          98          38          94          98           3
5          91          27          90          75          75          96          67          38          92
6          20          18          95          98          27          11          70          46          84
  var 10 lag 1 var 11 lag 1 var 12 lag 1 var 13 lag 1 var 14 lag 1 var 15 lag 1 var 16 lag 1 var 17 lag 1 var 18 lag 1
1           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2            6           88           60            6           63           94           81           64           95
3           35           97           95            5           21           56           48          100            7
4           58           87           12           98           91           57           17           51           37
5           54           44           52           80           59           10           40           94           67
6           61           19           94            3           17           39           82           19            1
  var 19 lag 1 var 20 lag 1 var 1 lag 2 var 2 lag 2 var 3 lag 2 var 4 lag 2 var 5 lag 2 var 6 lag 2 var 7 lag 2
1           NA           NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
2           77           28          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
3           59           75          26          27          66          82          86          53          37
4           72           61          37          22          18          93           3          69          74
5           28           51          57          52          96          14          98          38          94
6           44           88          91          27          90          75          75          96          67
```

Comment: Seems a Good option for me as well, but I was looking for a data.table solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift` and `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(foo = seq_len(10),
                 bar = seq_len(10)*2L,
                 baz = seq_len(10)*3L)

LagCols <- c("bar","baz")
LagLengths <- seq_len(2)

for(y in LagCols){
  for (z in LagLengths) set(DT, j = eval(paste0(y,"_lag_",z)), value = shift(DT[[y]],n = z, type = "lag"))
}

print(DT)
```

gives the following:

```
    foo bar baz bar_lag_1 bar_lag_2 baz_lag_1 baz_lag_2
 1:   1   2   3        NA        NA        NA        NA
 2:   2   4   6         2        NA         3        NA
 3:   3   6   9         4         2         6         3
 4:   4   8  12         6         4         9         6
 5:   5  10  15         8         6        12         9
 6:   6  12  18        10         8        15        12
 7:   7  14  21        12        10        18        15
 8:   8  16  24        14        12        21        18
 9:   9  18  27        16        14        24        21
10:  10  20  30        18        16        27        24
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If you haven't already come across it, I've found Andrew Brooks post on [Advanced tips and tricks with data.table](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/) to have a lot of  really useful snippets, that's one of the key articles that helped me understand how to leverage some of these specific concepts.